# Keras Flatten layer returns output shape (None, None)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So, I noticed this strange behavior of Flatten layer of Keras. I'm using TF1.15 and Keras 2.3.0.

Basically the output of the Flatten layer has an unknown shape. It's hard to troubleshoot the model when you can't keep track of the shape. Why is this happening with Flatten layer, and can I do something so it recognizes the shape?

```
from keras.layers import Flatten
inputs = Input(shape=(3,2,4))
prediction = Flatten()(inputs)
print(inputs.shape, prediction.shape)

(?, 3, 2, 4) (?, ?)
```

Answer (score 3):

Try using `tf.keras` instead of just `keras`:

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)
inputs = tf.keras.layers.Input(shape=(3,2,4))
prediction = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)
print(inputs.shape, prediction.shape)
```

```
1.15.2
(?, 3, 2, 4) (?, 24)
```

Comment: That does work. I guess the problem for me is that my Input is in keras.layers.Input format. And if I do `inputs = Input(shape=(3,2,4)); prediction = tf.keras.layers.Flatten()(inputs)`, I get `AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'layer'` error. Is there a way to convert between two formats?

Comment: They should *not* be mixed up. Why can't you use `tf.keras.layers.Input`?

Comment: I'm using another model as a backbone that already is written with Keras syntax.

Comment: You will unfortunately have to stick to one of them or rewrite the other model using `tf.keras` and just add the trained weights from the old Keras model to it (have not tested, possible that it will not work) @MikeAzatov

Comment: That sucks. It would be really nice to have a workaround for this. The models I'm working with are quite big and re-writing them would take me weeks.

Comment: I mean if it just the shape of a flatten layer, you can easily derive the output shape manually based on the previous layer